# "Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()" and other Proguard and Firebase issues

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-proguard, firebaseui

I'm at wits end with Proguard and Firebase. Proguard seems to be causing issue after issue with the release version of [my Play Store app](https://github.com/langsmith/ChildChip).

Here's what's is currently in my proguard-rules.pro file:

```
-keepattributes Signature

-keepclassmembers class com.test.finalapp.models.** { *;}


-keep class com.test.finalapp.viewholders.** { *; }

-dontwarn android.support.v7.**
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }

-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepclassmembers class ** {
    @org.greenrobot.eventbus.Subscribe <methods>;
}
-keep enum org.greenrobot.eventbus.ThreadMode { *; }

-keepclassmembers class ** { public void onEvent*(**); }
```

I'm using a FirebaseUI RecyclerView adapter and that adapter's viewholder class is in the viewholders package name. So that's what that line in the proguard-rules.pro file is for.

Side question: Does capitalization matter in the proguard-rules file?  Should viewholders be capitalized in "com.test.finalapp.viewholders" if my package is named "Viewholders"?

ANYWAYS, here's the latest logcat error that I can't figure out:

```
09-16 16:16:46.899 882-882/? E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()
                                                      at com.google.firebase.database.g.a(Unknown Source)
                                                      at com.test.finalapp.Activities.PreMainActivities.c.a(Unknown Source)
                                                      at com.google.firebase.database.p.a(Unknown Source)
                                                      at com.google.android.gms.c.ha.a(Unknown Source)
                                                      at com.google.android.gms.c.iv.b(Unknown Source)
                                                      at com.google.android.gms.c.jb.run(Unknown Source)
                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:152)
                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5507)
                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
09-16 16:16:47.102 882-882/? D/FirebaseCrashApiImpl: throwable java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()

                                                     --------- beginning of crash
09-16 16:16:47.141 882-882/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: com.test.finalapp, PID: 882
                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()
                                                   at com.google.firebase.database.g.a(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.test.finalapp.Activities.PreMainActivities.c.a(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.firebase.database.p.a(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.c.ha.a(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.c.iv.b(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.c.jb.run(Unknown Source)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:152)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5507)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I have no clue what ""Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()" means, nor what to adjust to solve the problem. Thoughts? I couldn't find any solutions online before posting this question...

Comment: same problem :(

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that when putting variables in the Android Studio Watches windows, and one of them is a static ref like this, hence the `StreetsId.PUSH_ID`

```
country + "/"+ FirebaseManager.STREET_ADDRESS +"/"+ snapshot.child(StreetsId.PUSH_ID).getValue()
```

The Watches window is producing that error message in the Android Studio debugger console window indeed.